# extjs error on filling store

Tags: json, extjs, charts, store

I have a java map. I converted it to json string and I obtain something like this :

```
{"NEW ZEALAND":"111111111111111","CHAD":"1","MOROCCO":"111","LATVIA":"11"}
```

Now I want to use it in a store and then a chart like the following code but it's not working. I have no error just no display.

```
var obj = Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: App.rootPath + '/controller/home/dashboard/test.json',
  method:'GET',
  success: function(response) {          
    return Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
  }
});

var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'PopulationPoint',
  data: obj
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
  renderTo: 'infos2',
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  store: store2,
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      field: 'population',
      label: {
        field: 'state',
        display: 'rotate',
        font: '12px Arial'
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX request is asynchronous. As such, the `obj` variable used to initialize your data won't contain your data yet.

One option is to create the `store2` variable and create the chart directly in the success callback of the AJAX request.

A cleaner option would be to configure the store with a proxy to load the url, and in the callback create the chart.

**EDIT**

The JSON response does not contain the fields that are declared in your model (sent in the comments). Update the JSON to return a properly formatted model and the chart should work as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpastore84/2w7jpg9L/1/). The JSON should look something like

```
[
    {
      "state" : "New Zealand",
      "population" : 111111111
    },
    {
      "state" : "Chad",
      "population" : 1
    }
]
```

Comment: I tried the first solution but same issue, and when i try to display the content of the store with store2.each(function(record) {
         console.log(record);
     });  the result is seems to be ok no ? (see my edited post)

Comment: Can you post your population point model? I'm curious to see how the model declares the field and the reader.

Comment: Ext.define('PopulationPoint', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['state', 'population']
    });

Comment: Your JSON doesn't align to those fields. It should be something like this: `[{"state":"NEW ZEALAND","population":10000}, {"state":"CHAD", "population": 123123123}]`

Comment: so I can declare a global model like : Ext.define('PopulationPoint', { extend: 'Ext.data.Model', fields: ['state':'value1', 'population':'value2'] }); ? or something like that ?

Comment: No, your model is correct. The JSON response should be an array of objects, with a key for each field name defined in your model, and the value set to whatever the value is for that key.

Comment: ok but key and values in my json object  can change, it's generated dynamically in my java controller then transformed in json

Comment: The chart will render it correctly. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpastore84/2w7jpg9L/1/) is a simplified fiddle that you can play with. Try adding/removing a data object from the store and you'll see the chart will update accordingly. It's just a matter of getting the JSON correct.